"Error installing @kolkov/angular-editor: ERESOLVE issue with ngx-cookie-service dependency"
I'm encountering an issue while trying to install the @kolkov/angular-editor or (any editor) package using npm. Whenever I run npm install @kolkov/angular-editor --save, I receive an error message with code ERESOLVE. The error seems to be related to resolving dependencies for another package, ngx-cookie-service@17.1.0, which requires @angular/common@15.2.10. However, my project is using @angular/common@15.2.10 along with @angular/forms@15.2.10 and @angular/platform-browser@15.2.10, all of which are specified in the package.json file. Despite this, npm is unable to resolve the dependencies properly. Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!( i cant upgrade version because i work with team)
I attempted to install the @kolkov/angular-editor package using npm, expecting it to be installed successfully. However, I encountered an ERESOLVE issue related to the ngx-cookie-service dependency.
I also tried forcing installation ngx-quill last version
